# Why is numpy faster at finding non-zero elements in a matrix?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

```
def nonzero(a):      
    row,colum = a.shape
    nonzero_row = np.array([],dtype=int)
    nonzero_col = np.array([],dtype=int)
    for i in range(0,row):
        for j in range(0,colum):
            if a[i,j] != 0:
                nonzero_row = np.append(nonzero_row,i)
                nonzero_col = np.append(nonzero_col,j)
    return (nonzero_row,nonzero_col)
```

The above code is much slower compared to

```
(row,col) = np.nonzero(edges_canny)
```

It would be great if I can get any direction how to increase the speed and why numpy functions are much faster?

Comment: Numpy array functions are implemented in C, which is a very fast language compiled to machine code.

Comment: And some stuff (e.g. dot and all dot-users like norm and co.) is even using [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms)/LAPACK which was optimized over decades with much care about simd- and caching-behaviour of  cpu's (and also multithreading), although i'm not sure if that's used in your example.

Comment: @DYZ A lot of Python is also implemented in C. The C in CPython isn't just there by accident. The difference is that numpy arrays store the values as native (C types) `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, ... values instead of as python (arbitary precision) integers or wrapped `double`s.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 reasons why NumPy functions can outperform Pythons types:

- The values inside the array are native types, not Python types. This means NumPy doesn't need to go through the abstraction layer that Python has.
- NumPy functions are (mostly) written in C. That actually only matters in some cases because a lot of Python functions are also written in C, for example `sum`.

In your case you also do something really inefficient: You append to an array. That's one **really expensive** operation in the middle of a double loop. That's an obvious (and unnecessary) bottleneck right there. You would get amazing speedups just by using lists as `nonzero_row` and `nonzero_col` and only convert them to array just before you return:

```
def nonzero_list_based(a):      
    row,colum = a.shape
    a = a.tolist()
    nonzero_row = []
    nonzero_col = []
    for i in range(0,row):
        for j in range(0,colum):
            if a[i][j] != 0:
                nonzero_row.append(i)
                nonzero_col.append(j)
    return (np.array(nonzero_row), np.array(nonzero_col))
```

The timings:

```
import numpy as np

def nonzero_original(a):      
    row,colum = a.shape
    nonzero_row = np.array([],dtype=int)
    nonzero_col = np.array([],dtype=int)
    for i in range(0,row):
        for j in range(0,colum):
            if a[i,j] != 0:
                nonzero_row = np.append(nonzero_row,i)
                nonzero_col = np.append(nonzero_col,j)
    return (nonzero_row,nonzero_col) 


arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, (100, 100))
%timeit np.nonzero(arr)
# 315 µs ± 5.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit nonzero_original(arr)
# 759 ms ± 12.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit nonzero_list_based(arr)
# 13.1 ms ± 492 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Even though it's 40 times slower than the NumPy operation it's still more than 60 times faster than your approach. There's an important lesson here: **Avoid `np.append` whenever possible!**

---

One additional point why NumPy outperforms alternative approaches is because they (mostly) use state-of-the art approaches (or they "import" them, i.e. BLAS/LAPACK/ATLAS/MKL) to solve the problems. These algorithms have been optimized for correctness and speed over **years** (if not decades). You shouldn't expect to find a faster or even comparable solution.

Comment: I think that it's also important to note that numpy functions (in C) will frequently beat python functions (in C).  The reason is because numpy arrays have a very predictable memory layout that allows for more efficient cache usage and for optimizations like SIMD instructions, etc.

Comment: @mgilson That's right - but it's not so easy to explain. In CPython lists are also wrappers around C arrays. The difference is mostly in the abstraction layer because each item in such an array is a pointer to another python object. But Python uses a clever way to allocate objects so in many cases caching can be quite effective. I thought Python also benefits from SIMD instructions (but I could be wrong). The abstraction layer is definetly the source of all the performance "problems" but what exactly happens isn't so easy to explain (at least for me).